# How to get the noise based on the original image and denoised image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am doing a denoising work and I'm not very familiar with Python. I applied BM3D to get the denoised picture and I also have the original one.

Now I want to get the noise by doing this:

```
tmp = img - img_denoised
```

But it turns out to be a very strange black and white figure like this:

[image: denoised picture]

So how can I get a proper noise picture? What I wish to get is image like this:
[image: image wanted]

Edit:
Got an image from the Internet and done the same processing.

[image: original]

after processing:

[image: processed]

Edit again:

Providing a simple example:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("path of the original image")

img_denoised = cv2.imread("path of the denoised image")

tmp = img - img_denoised

cv2.imwrite("test_noise.jpg",tmp)
```

[image: result]

Comment: @Bilal sorry but uploading image on the Internet used may cause some troubles... Since I've got both denoised and original image, how to get the image of noise has little to do with the actual image I think.

Comment: Indeed. But you can still post a [mre]: take any other image, add some noise, take the difference as your noise image, display it. I presume you have a problem with how you display the image, but it could also be an issue with types.

Comment: Again, please show a [mre]. We don’t need to see your denoising code, write a short program that loads those two images you just posted, takes the difference, and displays the result. So that we can see how you do those things. Make sure your example program reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I've updated a simple example, maybe it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, both `img` and `img_denoised` are `uint8` NumPy arrays. When operating on these arrays, the output is of the same type. These operations are modulo 256. When the result of an operation exceeds 255, it wraps around back to 0, and when the result is negative, it wraps around back to 255. For example:

```py
np.array([5], np.uint8) - np.array([10], np.uint8)
```

return `array([251], dtype=uint8)`. Instead of -5, which cannot be represented in a `uint8` value, we get 256 - 5 = 251.

The subtraction `img - img_denoised` results in some values just above zero, which look black, and some values just below zero, which will be stored as values near 255 and look white.

We can solve this in different ways. One is to force the operation to happen with floating-point values:

```py
tmp = img.astype(float) - img_denoised.astype(float)
```

We now have an array of floats, about half of them negative. But a JPEG file can only store `uint8` values, and casting our float values to `uint8` will get us back where we started. So we need to shift the origin (the zero value) to a middle-gray (typically 128):

```py
tmp = img.astype(float) - img_denoised.astype(float)
tmp += 128
cv2.imwrite("test_noise.jpg", tmp.astype(np.uint8))
```

This is very fiddly, but it works. I prefer using a library that takes care of data types for me, so I don't have to think about them when I don't want to. [DIPlib](http://www.diplib.org) is such a library (disclaimer: I'm an author):

```py
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageRead("7yJS3.png")
img_denoised = dip.ImageRead("xjQIy.png")

tmp = img - img_denoised
tmp += 128
dip.ImageWrite(tmp, "test_noise.jpg")
```

In DIPlib, arithmetic operations automatically promote the images to a floating-point type, unless we explicitly prevent it. Saving as JPEG silently casts the image to `uint8` (this is where errors will happen if the pixel values are outside the range of the `uint8` type).

Comment: Thanks very much! It solves my problem and now I can get a proper image!

Answer (score 0):

With limited information it is hard to pin-point the problem. Please provide input images and more code.

Looks like the result image is a binary bitmap, only white or black, no gray. Your tmp image's pixel format is probably incorrect, which might be due to your img and img_denoised are not having the same pixel format, or both are wrong. Try display your input images to see if they look normal.

Your img and img_denoised should be the same pixel format, maybe 8-bit gray scale, or 24-bit RGB, and after `img-img_denoised`, the result should still have the same pixel format.

It could also due to it's unsigned, try to make it signed, or + 128 to all pixels and see what happened.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I updated the question, not knowing whether enough imformation is  provided. Also BM3D algorithm is rather complex so I don't know how much to put my code on it.

Comment: If you can’t answer the question, please don’t post an answer. You can comment to ask for clarification, and you can flag the question for review.

Answer (score 0):

What is your image data type/range? 0-1 or 0-255?

if your image is 0-1 float32, the noise image will have a data range of [-1, 1], around half of the pixels is below 0, and when displayed by `cv2.imshow()` as "black".

Try

```
noise = origin - clean
noise = (noise + 1) * 0.5
```

Comment: Thx for answering! I tried your method but it turns out to be an image with black and gray... But maybe it's the problem about types? I will figure it out later.